Rufus external (USB) Windows 10 bootable SSD is damaging intenal HDD file system
I used Rufus to create an external (USB) Windows 10 bootable SSD.
I use this SSD to start different computers (I press F12/F8 key to show the boot menu and then choose my SSD), then when I restart the computer using the OS on the internal HDD/SSD (usually Windows 11) I get a message saying that the file system is damaged and need to be repaired, sometimes Windows 11 is able to fix the file system, but sometimes it is not.
How can I solve this problem, or how can I make the internal HDD/SSD read only or invisible?
I mean, how can I make my Rufus bootable SSD don't even touch the internal HDD/SSD?

Have you correctly shut down the original system before booting to the external SSD? And have you disabled "Fast Startup" on the Windows installation on the SSD? Windows by default does not fully shut down but performs a hibernate on the kernel system which means the file-systems are not closed and if you boot into a different system then the other OS will recognize that the file-system wasn't shut down.

@Robert Thank you very much for your answer. I always shut down by clicking on Start icon --> Power --> Shutdown, but I use different computers at the university, so I don't know if the previous user shoot down the system properly.  No, I have not disabled "Fast Startup". I will try it.  "Windows by default does not fully shut down but performs a hibernate on the kernel system ..." Is my Windows 10-SSD storing this hibernate-state on the internal drive?

Rufus dev here.

How can I solve this problem, or how can I make the internal HDD/SSD read only or invisible?

Simple. You need to select the Prevent Windows To Go from accessing internal drives option when creating the drive in Rufus (which you will see in the Windows User Experience prompt that Rufus displays when you create a Windows To Go drive).
And indeed, the reason there is such an option is that Microsoft did not design Windows to play nice with other existing installations, and, unless you explicitly tell is so, an instance of Windows may try to access any disk it can access, and mess with the file system. For instance, you may lose access to ReFS media if you boot a Windows 11 instance on a system that uses Windows 10 with ReFS, because Windows silently upgrades the ReFS version of any ReFS file system it sees, and ReFS is not backward compatible.
And that is why Rufus has a prominent option to do exactly what you seek, which you appear to have missed.

One reason to use a bootable external drive is to access the internal drive. While your answer is valid, it prevents such use. The most common reason the file system shows issues on reboot to the internal drive is that the last Windows session was not fully shut down. Hibernate, Sleep. Fast Startup and Quick Boot all leave the disk "dirty", i.e., marked that there is an active session. Only a complete shutdown (e.g., shutdown /s /f /t 0) will make the internal drive safely writable. See https://lifehacker.com/shutting-down-windows-10-doesnt-actually-shut-down-wind-1825532376

@DrMoishePippik The OP did specifically ask "I mean, how can I make my Rufus bootable SSD don't even touch the internal HDD/SSD?" While this answer addresses that specific question, the overall solution is to do what you suggest

@Akeo Thank you very much for your answer, I remember seeing the option Prevent Windows To Go from accessing internal drives, I also remember I did not check it.  Is there a way to enable it now, or will I need to recreate the bootable SSD?

@Jaimitove, you will be better off recreating the media. Or you can look on setting the SAN policy which is what controls access, but I can make no guarantee that what you find then will work. @DrMoishePippik, when using the now defunct official WTG Creator, Microsoft actually turned that policy on by default so your use is not common case.

@Akeo OK. I will recreate my SSD. Thank you so much for your help.
